# Calc: display name of cell instead of its value or formula

Tags: libreoffice

Libreoffice Calc 'normally' displays the value of the cell.

A user can change the display from values to formulas by putting a check mark in the config-box called Formulas in the config popup: Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice Calc -> View -> Display

Is there a way to change the display to show the names a user may have given to the cells?  Or is there something similar?

By "cell name", I am referring to:

https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Naming_Cells

Comment: In order to clarify your question, with cell naming one can, for instance, name a range of cells so that possibly many cells can be referred to by that name in a formula.  What would you expect to see in terms of "show the names" if an range of cells were so named?

Answer (score 1):

If you are refering to:

[Cell names](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Naming_Cells).

Then `CTRL-F3` (Manage names) will get you to the list of names defined.